# Postage of 3 pence or more using just 3-pence and 4-pence stamps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Question: **"Find the flaw with the following "proof" that every postage of three pence or more can be formed using just three-pence and four-pence stamps.**

**Basis step: we can form postage of three pence with a single three-pence stamp and we can form postage of four pence using a single four-pence stamp.**

**Inductive step:  assume we can form postage of $j$ pence for all integers $j$ where $3≤j≤k$ using just three-pence and four-pence stamps.  We can then form postage of $k+ 1$ pence by replacing one three-pence stamp with a four-pence stamp or by replacing two four-pence stamps by three three-pence stamps."**

I think the flaw is in the inductive step, as it doesn't show that postage of five pence can be formed. How could I explain this more formally?

Comment: What if there are not two four-pence stamps?

Comment: It might be a better exercise to ask for a correct inductive proof that every postage amount of six pence or more can be formed from three- and four-pence stamps.  This will help to highlight the importance of the number of base cases used to start the induction.

Comment: Since you correctly found that the proof doesn't cover the case of 5 pence, you should re-read the proof with that specific value in mind. The proof purports to show how to produce $k+1$ pence if you know how to produce smaller amounts. So fix $k$ to be 4; the proof now purports to produce 5p if you know how to produce 3p and 4p (which you do). So read the proof in this special case and see why it's wrong. (You'll get the same answer as Arnaud Mortier gave you, but I think you'll understand induction better if you chase down the error this way on your own.)

Comment: By the way, is this an ancient problem? Or in what country is postage still just a few pence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw is in the inductive step: nothing ensures that the set of stamps at step $k$ will contain a three-pence stamp or two four-pence stamps. The inductive step as it is written works only if one of these conditions is met.

[In fact, one can prove that it will be met for all $k$ except precisely $k=4$.]